# What's needed in a complete ASP.NET environment?

Tags: asp.net, deployment

We have a ASP3.0 application with a few ASP.NET (2.0) dittys mixed in. (Our longtime goal is to migrate everything to ASP.NET but that's not important for this issue)

Our current test/deploy workflow is like this:

```
1 Use notepad++ or VS2008 to fix a bug/feature (depending on what I have open)
2 Open my virtual test-server
3 Copy the fixed file over, either with explorer, or if I can be bothered to open it, WinMerge
4 Test that the fix works
5 Close the virtual test-server
6 Connect to our host with VPN
7 Use WinMerge to update the files necessary
8 Pray to higher powers that the production environment is not so different that something bombs.
```

To make things worse, only I have access to my "test-server". So I'm the only one testing it.

I really want to make this a bit more robust, I even have a subversion setup running. But I always forget to commit changes... And I don't even work in my checked out folder, but a copy of what is currently in production...

Can someone recommend some good reading on deploying, testing, staging and stuff like that. I currently use VS2008 and want to use subversion or GIT (or any other free VCS). Since I'm the only developer, teamsystem is not really an option (cost-related).
I have found myself developing an "improved" feature, only to find a bug in the same feature in the production system. And since my "improved" feature incorporated deleting some old functionality, I have to fix bugs directly in production... That's not a fun feeling...

(I have inherited this system recently... So it's not directly my fault that it is like this ;) )

Comment: Should migrate this to StackOverflow as it is all about development tools & process.

Comment: I put it here because a similar question on SO was migrated here... Where should environment and deployment questions be put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very roughly.

Here's what you need:

1. Central sourcecode repository (SVN, Git, or any other modern VCS)
2. [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server (see [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) or [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET))
3. Tool similar to [Chinchillin](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-chinchillin/) or MSDeploy

And here's how your process should look like:

1. You check out latest source code to your dev box
2. Fix it here, test, fix again
3. When fixed, commit changes to the repository
4. Press a button in a CI dashboard that will build and deploy *staging* version of your website
5. Test your website on a staging server
6. Press yet another button in a CI dashboard that will take previously built *staging version* (this is crucial!) of your webapp and deploy it to the production.

For branching, you may refer to [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/agile-version-control) article for inspiration and ideas.

Comment: Yes.. This is the workflow I have been thinking about. The only thing missing here is working on different branches of the code (ref the new feature old bug scenario I mentioned)

Comment: @Christian See my edit.

Comment: That article was good. I could adapt that to single-user with some tinkering...
How would you do CI with ASP.NET/cASP ?

Comment: @Christian Doing CI for ASP(.NET) is not much different than doing CI with anything else. For a list of CI servers, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks man... That InfoQ article really helped me. Now lets see if I can make some progress in this mess ;)